# ¿Es posible devolver una cadena de caracteres a través de la sentencia return en C?

Tags: c, string

Buenos dias.
Me gustaría saber si es posible devolver una cadena o string, a través de la sentencia return en C, hasta el momento se que se puede devolver variables de tipo int y char, pero no se como hacerlo con la cadena. 
Un ejemplo seria llamar desde el main a una función denominada x, a la cual le paso un parámetro de tipo int por valor, en esa funcion creo una cadena de caracteres que dependiendo de la cantidad de la variable int rellena la cadena de caracteres con guiones, ejemplo la variable pasada por valor era 6 y en la funcion la cadena se rellena con 6 guiones. 
Volviendo a la pregunta como podria devolver esa cadena creada en esa funcion x con el return, acaso se puede hacer, como habréis leido no he mencionado de que tipo tendría  que ser la funcion si int o char para que funcione y la devuelva.

Comment: Deberías expresar mejor la pregunta, puesto que: `¿Es posible devolver una cadena de caracteres a través de la sentencia return en C? => La respuesta es si, si es posible`, ahora que no sea posible bajo determinadas limitaciones que propone tu profesor es otro tema «Quizás deberías listar esas limitaciones»

Answer (score 4):

Modificando brevemente el ejemplo que mostraste, podrías hacer así:

Solución usando variable por referencia:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

void cadena_guiones(char cadena[], int longitud); //Prototipo

int main(){
    int longitud=2;
    char cadena[25];
    cadena_guiones(cadena, longitud);
    printf("%s\n",cadena);
    return 0;
}

void cadena_guiones(char cadena[], int longitud) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<longitud;i++){
        cadena[i]='-';
    }
    cadena[i]='\0';
}
```

Solución usando arreglo dinámico:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *cadena_guiones(int longitud); //Prototipo

int main(){
    int longitud=2;
    printf("%s\n",cadena_guiones(longitud));
    return 0;
}

char *cadena_guiones(int longitud){
    int i;
    char *cad = (char*) malloc(25);
    for(i=0;i<longitud;i++){
        cad[i]='-';
    }
    cad[i]='\0';
    return cad;
}
```

Comment: Te doy las gracias, pero el problema es que no puedo hacer uso de la memoria dinámica ni de la sentencia new.

Comment: Solo remplaza por esta linea: `char *cad = (char*) malloc(25);`, de igual forma actualizare la respuesta para tu problema.

Comment: Ya se que la sentencia new se utiliza para la memoria dinámica en c++ y malloc para c, te repito que en el ejercicio que tengo que realizar no puedo utilizar memoria dinámica, tengo que resolverlo de la manera propuesta, muchas gracias. Simplemente querría saber si se puede devolver una cadena estática a través de la sentencia return.

Comment: Pues la manera mas fácil es que usases una variable por referencia `void cadena_guiones(char cadena[], int longitud)` así no usas malloc.

Comment: Ya si lo se, pero en el enunciado el profesor pone que la cadena se tiene que crear en la función y devolverla al main a través del return y ademas no se puede hacer uso de la memoria dinámica, es por eso que unos compañeros y yo estamos pensando que se ha equivocado en el enunciado porque es imposible realizarlo de ese modo que ha propuesto. Ademas de que hay maneras más eficientes y simples como las que propones.

Comment: puedes indicarnos que tema estais dando? porque si habeis hablado de memoria dinamica es porque habeis tratado el tema de punteros. No será que tu profesor quiere que hagas algo con ellos?. En general, puedes definir en una función de forma "dinamica" una cadena, pero no vas a poder devolverla. Te pongo un ejemplo como solucion.

Comment: ¿No es C++ lo que has puesto?

Comment: Gracias @NaCl, mala costumbre de mi parte que uso C++, sin embargo es solo cuestión de cambiar algunos detalles «una librería por otra» y funciona «testeado en https://www.codechef.com/ide» [Hice el cambio en la respuesta para mejorarla]

Answer (score 0):

La **única** forma de devolver un *array* de caracteres (o de cualquier otra cosa) en C, **sin** usar punteros, es usando un *contenedor auxiliar*, una `struct`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct aux {
  char text[100];
};

struct aux test( void ) {
  struct aux a = { 0 };

  strcat( a.text, "¡ Hola, mundo !" );
  return a;
}

int main( void ) {
  struct aux a = test( );

  printf( "%s\n", a.text );

  return 0;
}
```

En el código anterior, la función `test( )` devuelve **por valor** una `struct aux { }`, la cual tiene un miembro de tipo `char[100]`. Dicha devolución se realiza de forma correcta: **se copia toda la `struct`, icluido el *array* interno**.

Esta técnica tiene una **importante limitación**: el tamaño del *array* es **fijo**. **No** es posible hacer algo parecido para *array*s de tamaño desconocido.

Answer (score 0):

En general, si puedes definir de forma dinámica una cadena de caracteres en una función, sin necesidad de asignar memoria. Solo tienes que definirla al principio de la función, como si fuera una variable más:

```
void nueva_cadena(int tam) {
    char cad[tam+1];
    int cont;

    for(cont = 0; cont < tam; cont++)
        cad[cont] = '-';

    cad[tam] = '\0';
    printf("%s", cad);
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior, cad[tam+1] es "dinámico" ya que depende de la variable tam que pasas por parámetro. Le añado un elemento más para el fin de cadena '\0'. De todas formas, internamente el [tam+1] de un array está pasando por el pre-compilador de C, y te hace internamente un malloc(), por lo que, en verdad, siempre estas haciendo memoria dinámica.

Lo que no vas a poder es **devolver** esa cadena, ya que ha sido definida en un **ámbito** de variable dentro de la función. Es decir, que sólo va a existir **durante** la ejecución de esa función.

Si intentas hacer un **return cad;** probablemente te dará un warning.

Comment: Especificar también que no todos los compiladores soportan Arrays de longitud variable, y que esta funcionalidad es específica de C99, y ha sido eliminada en C++.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos!

Esto te podría servir:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *obtener_cadena(int n)
{

  char cad[n];
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
     cad[i] = '_';
  }

  cad[i] = '\0';

  return strdup(cad);
}

int main(void){

  char *txt = obtener_cadena(10);

  printf("%s\n", txt);


  return 0;
}
```

Puedes usar la función `strdup`, para poder retornar el valor de una cadena como arreglo `char[]` como si fuera un puntero de cadena `char*`