# ¿Cómo convertir palabras en mayúsculas en C?

Tags: c

Estoy creando una función la cual le paso una cadena de texto y esa cadena la convierto a mayúsculas con el método toupper() y la devuelvo con el método return, pero al hacerlo me genera error, este es el código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

char *mayus(char texto []){
char *result = toupper(texto);
return result;
}

void main(){
printf("%s",mayus("hola mundo");
}
```

Pero al ejecutar el código me genera el siguiente error:

Note: expected "int" but argument si of type "char *"

Cómo podría solucionarlo, o que otro método podría utilizar

Comment: Si no me equivoco, `toupper()` puede convertir un solo caracter a mayúsculas, no una cadena completa... por la cual podrías recorrer la cadena y convertir cada caracter

Comment: Aqui tienes una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80336/es-posible-devolver-una-cadena-de-caracteres-a-trav%c3%a9s-de-la-sentencia-return-en) con respuestas sobre tu problema,  como te dijo el compañero @Cris223511.dev, toupper() recibe un caracter a la vez o un integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como uno de los comentarios menciona, la función `toupper()` es para convertir un solo carácter a su forma mayúscula por tanto tendrías que iterar el texto y aplicar `toupper()` letra por letra:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
//Librerias agregadas...
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char *mayus(char texto[]) {
   unsigned long int texto_len = strlen(texto);  //tamaño del del argumento texto 

    char *textoMayus = malloc(sizeof(char) * texto_len); //reservando memoria para la variable a retornar

    for (int i = 0; i < texto_len; i++)
    {
        textoMayus[i] = toupper(texto[i]); 
    }

    return textoMayus;
}


void main(){
    
    printf("%s",mayus("hola mundo"));

}
```

Agregué las librerías `string.h` para la función `strlen()` y `stdlib.h` para la función `malloc()`.

**Este código es una adaptación de una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181913/converting-char-to-uppercase-in-c) del foro en ingles de Stack overflow donde se presentaba la misma problematica.**

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me funciono

Comment: Me podrías explicar cómo funciona la línea donde está malloc() por favor,no se como Funciona

Comment: malloc lo que hace es reservar espacio de memoria, en este caso reserva un tamaño igual a char por la cantidad de letras en el texto, ¿por qué tome esta medida? para evitar problemas en el return, bien se podría hacer sin el malloc y devolver el char* pero te saldría una advertencia de que estas tratando de retornar un char* local (cosa que cuenta como puntero) hacia afuera.